# Euler characteristic in 4 dimension

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a 4-dimensional compact manifold (torsion free), the Euler characteristic is defined as:

$E_4 = \int \epsilon_{abcd}R^{ab} \wedge R^{cd}$

with $R^{ab}$ is the curvature 2-form. Perturb the connection 1-form (represent by $\delta \omega^{ab}$), $E_4$ should be unchanged. How can I proof that, and what will be change if the manifold is not torsion free anymore?

Given that:

Connection 1-form from torsion-free condition:

$T^a = 0 = De^a = de^a + \omega^a_b \wedge e^b = 0$ and $\omega^{ab} = \delta^{ac} \omega^b_c$

Curvature 2-form:

$R^{ab} = D\omega^{ab} = d\omega^{ab} + \omega^a_c \wedge \omega^{cb}$

Comment: I hope that [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4972v4) expository paper can help